# Chessbase 14 - How do I enumerate variations in it?

Tags: chessbase

How can I enumerate variations in CB with A) A1) A2) B) etc. to make them more readable?

Like this:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options > Notation > Structured Variations